# Class import produces undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm working on a Vue app and trying to build some helper classes:

file a.js:

```
export default class Base {//...}
```

file b.js:

```
import Base from "./a"
export default class Middle extends Base { // ... }
```

file c.js:

```
import Middle from "./b" // Middle here is undefined
export default class Final extends Middle { // ... }}
```

When I import Middle it is undefined and giving me `Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function` on the line of `extends Middle`

I've also tried

```
let Middle = class Middle .... 
export default Middle
```

Which should not make a difference as far as I know and it didn't solve the problem..

I'm building a component as a standalone library with:

**vue-cli-service build --target lib**

Comment: `Super expression must either be null or a function` ... you're missing something `export default class Middle extends Base { // ... }` .... i.e. `// ...` isn't enough to show what you've done wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found out that it was some kind of recursion. In the `Base` class I had a factory method that interprets a JSON and returns the corresponding `Final` class. This of course means I had to import the Final classes in the Base class' file.